# Is there a way could I use Python to check if a specific user is logged in to a VM?

Tags: python, windows, virtual-machine

Basically a file does not update properly if a certain user in my organization is not logged in to the VM. The certain user updates the file through task scheduler on the VM

Due to complicated permission issues, it is virtually impossible to change the account assigned to this task. If that user is not logged-in to the VM, then the task fails.

I would like to know with what way, using Python, could I check if that user is logged into the VM. Once I know the status of the user on the VM, or if the user is not logged in to the VM, I would then notify the team via e-mail. The latter part is pretty trivial compared to the former part.

So could someone please enlighten me on how I could Python to check if a specific user is logged in to a VM? The script can also run on the VM which should simplify the issue.
Thanks!

Comment: "with Python" is an unnecessary complication of the basic question. You're asking "how to find out who's logged on in Windows". That will lead to a couple of options, for example [these](https://serverfault.com/questions/598554/whats-the-best-way-to-see-logged-in-users-in-windows-server-2012). Once you have one that works for you, you can think about how to integrate that into Python.

Comment: You're indeed correct. 

Since posting the question, I found it easiest to run 'query user' with cmd through python and saving the output as a variable

Comment: There you go. :) If you could put the couple of lines that do that as an answer below, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

So you can basically run `query user` on CMD prompt to retrieve the list of users on your machine.

If you use the `subprocess` module, you can extract the output displayed by the CMD prompt.

In this case an example of doing so is as follows:

```
import subprocess
a_string = subprocess.getoutput('query user')
```